# memcpy where size is known at compile time

Tags: c++, performance, memcpy

I find myself tuning a piece of code where memory is copied using `memcpy` and the third parameter (size) is known at compile time.

The consumer of the function calling `memcpy` does something similar to this:

```
template <size_t S>
void foo() {
    void* dstMemory = whateverA
    void* srcMemory = whateverB
    memcpy(dstMemory, srcMemory, S) 
}
```

Now, I would have expected that the `memcpy` intrinsic was smart enough to realise that this:

```
foo<4>()
```

... Can replace the `memcpy` in the function with a 32 bit integer assignment. However, I surprisingly find myself seeing a >2x speedup doing this:

```
template<size_t size>
inline void memcpy_fixed(void* dst, const void* src) {
    memcpy(dst, src, size);
}


template<>
inline void memcpy_fixed<4>(void* dst, const void* src) { *((uint32_t*)dst) =  *((uint32_t*)src); }
```

And rewriting `foo` to:

```
 template <size_t S>
 void foo() {
    void* dstMemory = whateverA
    void* srcMemory = whateverB
    memcpy_fixed<S>(dstMemory, srcMemory) 
}
```

Both tests are on clang (OS X) with -O3. I really would have expected the `memcpy` intrinsic to be smarter about the case where the size is known at compile time.

My compiler flags are:

`-gline-tables-only -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -mno-omit-leaf-frame-pointer`

Am I asking too much of the c++ compiler or is there some compiler flag I am missing?

Comment: The Problem is that memcpy is actually a c function and does not know anything about templates...

Comment: memcpy is a function, so non of the 3 inputs has to be known at compile time. Using integer assignment has the performance advantage because of assumed aligned access and no function calling overhead. However, the assumed aligned access might lead to UB when such assumption is not true.

Comment: memcpy is an intrinsic. It certainly is not just a normal function with modern C compilers. Try adding alignment information (maybe an align hint).

Comment: Note that C++ has `std::copy`.

Comment: How do you compile? Are you asking your compiler to optimize (e.g. compile with `g++ -O2 -mtune=native -fverbose-asm -S` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...)?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I edited the question with my parameters.

Answer (score 6):

`memcpy` is not the same as `*((uint32_t*)dst) =  *((uint32_t*)src)`.

memcpy can deal with unaligned memory.

By the way, most modern compiler do replace memcpy of known size with suitable code emission. for small size it usually emit things like `rep movsb`, which may not be fastest by good enough in most case.

If you found your particular case you gain 2x speed and you think you need to speed it up, you are free to get your hand dirty (with clear comments).

Comment: @ThomasKejser for one call it might be, but If you use it on another type that's size is 4, how should the compiler generate another template for it?

Comment: @ThomasKejser You could specialize on [alignment_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/alignment_of).

Comment: @Calvin: Am I correct in asserting that Intel x86_64 - the alignment shouldn't be an issue?

Comment: x86_64 support unaligned access, but it may affect performance.

Comment: @Calvin: According to my tests, not very much (5-10%) on i7 and above. Since I don't really care (in this code base) about anything but Intel CPU - the optimisation seems like an easy win - even if the memory happens to be unaligned.

Comment: Have you try hinting the compiler and see what it emit? for clang you can do `__attribute__ ((aligned (4)))` or `std::aligned_storage`. Also remove the `void*` which cause the compiler to lost track, and pass the object's address directly.

Answer (score 1):

If both source and destination buffers are provided as function parameters:

```
template <size_t S>
void foo(char* dst, const char* src) {
    memcpy(dst, src, S);
}
```

then clang++ 3.5.0 uses `memcpy` only when `S` is big but it uses the `movl` instruction when `S = 4`.

However, your source and destination addresses are not parameters of this function and this seems to prevent the compiler from making this aggressive optimization.